Token to transfer reseller on Google Workspace Product
Is there any way to fetch token transfer of a customer who whishes to change your
Google Workspace reseller???
Ex:

Customer A bought Google Workspace Business Plan from reseller KingHost company.
After few months customer A is gonna change your google reseller who manages this Google Workspace payments to another reseller.
So, in the admin.google.com/TransferToken this token is generated and customer inform to new reseller Locaweb company.

I spent few times read about this method bellow but I'm not sure if this is for that purpose.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/generated/google-apis-admin_directory_v1/lib/google/apis/admin_directory_v1/service.rb#L3881
I try to use get_token method provided by gem 'google-api-client', '0.52.0'
I expected to return some token for a customer.
This is the error message when a run this call
Google::Apis::ClientError (PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.)

